# Does Python have any equivalents to Rust's multi-producer single-consumer (MPSC) channels?

Tags: python, channel

I would like to have a Python function that creates a transmitter / receiver channel pair with the same or similar [mechanism as Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/):

> These channels come in two flavors:
>
> 1. An asynchronous, infinitely buffered channel. The [`channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) function
>    will return a `(Sender, Receiver)` tuple where all sends will be
>    **asynchronous** (they never block). The channel conceptually has an
>    infinite buffer.
> 2. A synchronous, bounded channel. The [`sync_channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.sync_channel.html) function will
>    return a `(SyncSender, Receiver)` tuple where the storage for pending
>    messages is a pre-allocated buffer of a fixed size. All sends will be
>    **synchronous** by blocking until there is buffer space available. Note
>    that a bound of 0 is allowed, causing the channel to become a "rendezvous"
>    channel where each sender atomically hands off a message to a receiver.

Comment: Python has the `Queue` class that can be used this way.

Comment: You're looking for messaging library, maybe zeromq, rabbitmq, etc

Comment: For those of us not familiar with mpsc and which compromises you are willing to make, can you please explain what you expect this "channel" to provide?

Comment: As @TimRoberts answered, Python's version is `queue.Queue`, which is an mpmc. The interface is somewhat different, but aside from the same type handling both bounded and unbounded queues (the sync behaviour is performed at the callsite) the main divergence is the Python version has no support for rendezvous channels.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `queue.Queue` and you'll get an object that represents both sides of the channel. Pass it to your threads and call `q.get()` to receive and `q.put(item)` to send. There is no notion of closing the channel (achieved in Rust by dropping all producers), you'll need to send a sentinel value like `None`.